# How to set JavaFX password field echo char

Tags: java, javafx

In Swing, I can set echo char with `setEchoChar`:

```
new JPasswordField().setEchoChar('*');
```

How can i do the same in JavaFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind of ugly, but... the password mask character is hardcoded into the default skin.

What you will need to do is create your own skin and implement your own masking function.

There is an existing feature request for more flexible password masking functionality:

- [RT-39954
  Option to set a custom bullet/mask/placeholder in a PasswordField](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39954).

If anybody is interested in contributing the the open-jfx project for JavaFX development, this would be a nice simple way to start...

---

As background, here is the making code from the JavaFX 8 `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.java`:

```
// For use with PasswordField
public static final char BULLET = '\u2022';
. . .
@Override protected String maskText(String txt) {
    if (getSkinnable() instanceof PasswordField) {
        int n = txt.length();
        StringBuilder passwordBuilder = new StringBuilder(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            passwordBuilder.append(BULLET);
        }

        return passwordBuilder.toString();
    } else {
        return txt;
    }
}
```

So you can see that the `com.sun` class does not make it configurable.

Comment: ,did you mean we create a custom password field ,or override the default skin of password field ?

Comment: Change the skin of the PasswordField (you don't need to create a custom PasswordField), there is an example in the answer to the marked duplicate.

Comment: Yes , I did ,but the skin can only changed once time (in initialize method ) ,in runtime ( case of showing password characters) invokes some exceptions.

Comment: If you continue to have issues, please create a new question with a [mcve] that contains complete minimal code that somebody could use to copy and paste and replicate the issue.  In the new question, you can reference this question and the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

[You should just be able to use CSS styling for it.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/doc-files/cssref.html#passwordbox)

Example, in order to make the echo character a "-":

```
PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
passwordField.setStyle("-fx-echo-char: -;");
```

Comment: No, you can't.  That link is for styling a PasswordBox in the deprecated JavaFX script language, not for [styling a PasswordField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#passwordfield) in a modern JavaFX 8 implementation.