# Password field circles very large

Tags: javafx

When I use the password field in JavaFx, the circles masking the input are very large. Can the size be adjusted? Which property is it?

[image]

Comment: [MaterialFX MFXPasswordField](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX/wiki/Text-Fields#mfxpasswordfields) has a `-mfx-hide-character` css style if you want to use that.

Comment: Related: [Bullet to asterisk in a passwordField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688835/bullet-to-asterisk-in-a-passwordfield), [How to set JavaFX password field echo char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318404/how-to-set-javafx-password-field-echo-char).

Answer (score 4):

The masking character is defined as a final static field in the `TextInputControlSkin` class (it is defined as `static final char BULLET = '\u25cf';`), and the [`maskText()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextInputControlSkin.html#maskText(java.lang.String)) method is called to determine the text to be displayed. This is a `protected` method, so you can override it to change the masking character (or entire strategy, if you wish).

A minimal approach would be something like:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.password;

import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin;

public class PasswordFieldSkin extends TextFieldSkin {

    private static final String BULLET = "\u2022";


    public PasswordFieldSkin(PasswordField control) {
        super(control);
    }

    @Override
    protected String maskText(String text) {
        return BULLET.repeat(text.length());
    }
}
```

This uses a smaller bullet, `\u2022`, which is •. The default is `\u25cf`, which is ●. Other options are of course possible.

An example usage is:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.password;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        PasswordField standardPasswordField = new PasswordField();
        PasswordField smallBulletPasswordField = new PasswordField();
        smallBulletPasswordField.setSkin(new PasswordFieldSkin(smallBulletPasswordField));
        VBox fields = new VBox(5, standardPasswordField, smallBulletPasswordField);
        fields.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        fields.setPadding(new Insets(40));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fields);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

If you want to use this for all password fields in the application (which would make sense), you can specify the skin in CSS:

```
.password-field {
    -fx-skin: "org.jamesd.examples.password.PasswordFieldSkin";
}
```

and then the skin class above will become the default (obviously adjust to your own package name as needed).